# Parameter value becomes null at the second time, when one web api project ApiController calls another web api project ApiController, using HTTPClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, dotnet-httpclient

I try to file upload a 20MB file, I convert that file to contentAsBase64String format in angularjs(Client Side) and send to the FirstProject APIController.

The First Project APIController is calling the Second Project APIController method. When I upload the 20MB file,the first time everything is working fine.

Please refer the below image for First project APIController put method.
[image]

Getting value first time in second project APIController put method.
[image]

When I upload the file the second time the second project APIController getting null value.Please refer the below image.
[image]
Below mentioned second project WebConfig

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" maxRequestLength="2147483647"/>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: What is `Entiy` in the FirstProject the second time?

Comment: @RobertStettler: The FirstProject entity gets the value of DocumentViewmodel object the second time.(same as the first case).

Comment: I am missing relevant code from the client and the methods. I cannot reproduce the issue with the code you show. And the flow you mention gives no clues. Like Robert I would suspect that Entity in FirstProject is also null. So I'd have to guess what can cause this behavior. I think it is related to the content stream. Is there any chance that the stream is read (logged) somewhere in between the second time? Because it seems that the pointer is located at the end of the stream causing Entity to be null.